# Cloud Functions for Firebase - write to database when a new user created

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am pretty new Cloud Functions for Firebase and the javascript language. I am trying to add a function every time a user created to write into the database. This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
const user = event.data; // The firebase user
const id = user.uid;
const displayName = user.displayName;
const photoURL = user.photoURL;

return admin.database().ref.child("/users/${id}/info/status").set("ok");} );
```

what I am trying to do is every time a user signup to my app, the functions wil write into the database that his status is "OK". But my code dosn't work.
[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is that shouldn't use the ${id}, and I shouldn't have use the child. So the code should look like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data; // The firebase user
    const id = user.uid;
    const displayName = user.displayName;
    const photoURL = user.photoURL;

    return admin.database().ref("/users/"+id+"/info/status").set("ok"); 
});
```

Comment: You can use ``admin.database().ref(`/users/${id}/info/status/`)`` instead of `("/users/"+id+"/info/status")`. Use backticks instead of quotes for writing query strings