# How to send data from Google Pub/Sub to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I am new to the Google Cloud. I have a topic in Pub/Sub and have an IoT device that is sending data to it. How can I then send this data to Firebase Realtime DataBase? I have been looking for a while, but could not find a tutorial showing how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to have code somewhere that listen to the PubSub topic and then writes to the database. A common way to do this these days is to use Cloud Functions, which saves you from having to set up your own server. For a good explanation of this, see the Firebase documentation for [triggering Cloud Functions from PubSub](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events).

Then in that Cloud Function you'll need to write the data to the Realtime Database. For an example of writing to the database in a Cloud Function, see [Cloud Functions for Firebase - write to database when a new user created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482792/cloud-functions-for-firebase-write-to-database-when-a-new-user-created)

Also see:

- [Write to firebase database from cloud function triggered by PubSub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473933/write-to-firebase-database-from-cloud-function-triggered-by-pubsub)
- [How can I take data from google cloud pubsub to firebase realtime data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553425/how-can-i-take-data-from-google-cloud-pubsub-to-firebase-realtime-data-base)
- [How to push new data into firebase realtime database using cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941972/how-to-push-new-data-into-firebase-realtime-database-using-cloud-functions)

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. It gave me a good overview. I followed the instructions on the two links and it worked. One things that throw me off a bit and took sometime was that cloud functions are per project and cannot be triggered with Pub/Sub of another project. Right?

Comment: Yeah, the only cross-project Cloud Functions I know of are HTTPS.